# Powershell Query

Tags: shell, powershell, batch-file, psexec

HKU

```
\\<host>\HKU\<SID>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /s
```

Example:

```
for /f  "delims=\ tokens=2,*" %t in ('reg query HKU') do reg query HKU\%t         \Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /s
```

HKLM

```
reg query \\<host>\HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /s
```

Example:

```
FOR /F %i in (hosts.txt) DO @echo [+] %i && 
@reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /s 2>NUL > output.txt && 
FOR /F %n in (strings.txt) DO @type output.txt | findstr %n > NUL && 
echo [!] %n was found on %i!
```

Here are some examples that we have came up with at the office. But trying to figure out how to add in a psexec command to allow for us to query remote computers on the network.

So it would read the hosts from the hosts.txt file along with the strings from the strings.txt and possible add in a variable to change out the different registry keys. Then output it all into one text file.

Do you think this is too much to try in a batch file? What about a powershell script?
Thanks

Comment: Edit your post and add 4 spaces to the start of every line of code.  The editor has an option for code too.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I was using a XP machine and slow Internet at the time.

Answer (score 1):

To query remote registry keys with PowerShell use [`OpenRemoteBaseKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zha3xws%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', 'computer-name')
```

The first parameter is the hive name, a list of which can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctb3kd86.aspx). The second is the name of the computer to connect to.

This will return a [`Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx) object which you can use to list sub keys and read their values.

Here is an example of reading the run key values:

```
$path = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
$key = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', 'computer-name')
$subkey = $key.OpenSubKey($path)
$subkey.GetValueNames() | ForEach-Object {
    '{0} : {1}' -f $_, $subkey.GetValue($_)
}
```

Comment: +1 I think it's worth mentioning that the `RemoteRegistry` service must be running on the remote host, and IIRC admin privileges are required for accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the [PSRemoteRegistry](http://psremoteregistry.codeplex.com/) module:

```
 Get-RegValue -Hive LocalMachine -Key Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run -ComputerName server1
```

Comment: Now I haven't wrote power shell ever. Would it be a better choice to do over a batch file?

Comment: In my option yes but I'm biased :)

Comment: Good looking module Shay :)

Comment: I'll try it tonight. Posting from my mobile phone

Comment: Thanks @AndyArismendi. The v3 version is available here http://psrr.codeplex.com (Connecting to the 32/64-bit section of the remote server registry)

Comment: I would of thought `Get-RegValue` would return whatever the registry data is e.g. Multi-String=string array, DWORD=Int32, Binary=byte array. Like how Get-ItemProperty does it so you don't have to tell it what the type is before hand.

Comment: Oh sry, I was reading through it and saw `if($v -like $Value -AND $vk -like $t)`. Now I see `$t` defaults to `*` and it's not mandatory. So it does do what I was thinking :).